# problema virtualizacion amd ryzen android studio

Tags: android-studio, virtualización

hola gente estoy con problemas para intentar virtualizar en android studio, tengo un ryzen 5 3600 y al querer virtualizar me pide que instale Intel Haxm,pero sale este error al instalar:

> "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)
>   or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed.
>   Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the
>   Intel HAXM documentation for more information."

Ya activé la virtualización desde el BIOS y deshabilite Hyper-V en windows pero sigue sin funcionar.. alguna idea??

Answer (score 0):

Mucho tiempo después pero quizás ayude al que recién llega. Otra cosa que deberías hacer además de lo que ya hiciste, es habilitar la "Plataforma de hipervisor de Windows" desde "Agregar o quitar programas"